# Can a slim application live in a webserver where other applications (using other frameworks) are already working?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, slim

After hours of struggle I have come to the conclusion that the answer to my question is no, they can't.
Am I correct?
We have the following structure at work:

```
/var/www/html
           |___app1
           |___app2
           |___app3
```

App1, app2 and app3 are accessible like http://server_name/app1 (app2 , or app3)
These apps are created using different frameworks (angular, jquery with bootstrap, moca, etc) and there is no issue with them.
But I haven't been able to create an app4 using the slim project skeleton (slim4 in this case)....slim needs the document root to be the public folder and that crashes with the other applications.

I don't have the luxury to create virtual hosts by names or by IP.....DNS is not handled by my team and communication with networking IT is not possible (yes, that's rigt)....

I am able to make it work (the skeleton) if I change the DocumentRoot to /var/www/html/app4 (the slim app). But then all other apps stop working.

Is there a way to solve this under my conditions?

Thank you very much,

Andres

Comment: When you say you can't get it to run, what do you get when you access `http://server_name/app4`?

Comment: Thank you Nigel, I don't have access at this exact moment....But is something about resource not found error.  Correction:   http://server_name/app4 works....but I need http://server_name/app4/public   <--that's where the index.php lives on.

Comment: When you can, try changing the routes.php to see if you need to include the `/app4` as part of the route itself, it could be that it's using the full path, but the route is looking at `/` etc.

Comment: Sounds as though you would need to do some more juggling then with the file locations as well :(

Answer (score 0):

If it must be on the same domain. Have you considered using another port? It's not the most orthodox approach but I have set this up for staging environments at port 8080 while the live site lives at port 80. Would that work in your scenario? You would have to configure a virtual host to use port 8080.

Comment: Thank you Michael....I don't want to go the port option...I have the suspicion that my manager won't like that approach...Because we would need to ask IT for firewall changes  and it is always a pain when we need IT to be involved.

Comment: Hi MisterWalrus, it was worth a try but I understand it's not a great option! Are you on a linux server? If so, have you tried using a symbolic link? You could add one at app4 and point it to app4/public ?

Comment: Thank you very much Michael,  I just fixed it.....Nigel was right a little juggling with routes.php did the trick:  I have to add the /app4/public/login  to the routes, login does not exist under app4/public  so the .htaccess redirects to the index.php inside the public folder that handles the routes.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, there is a way to have slim frontend coexisting with the other apps in the same webserver, while sharing all the same DocumentRoot.
I Changed the routes.php to watch for all /app4/public/<any_entry_here> .

Like for example:

routes.php (that lives in /app4/app/routes.php)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
use App\Application\Actions\User\ListUsersAction;
use App\Application\Actions\User\ViewUserAction;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Interfaces\RouteCollectorProxyInterface as Group;

return function (App $app) {
$app->get('/app4/public/login', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
$response->getBody()->write('You have a slim4 app working now!');
return $response;
    });

};
```

Of course, under /app4/public lives index.php (and the corresponding .htaccess if using apache)

If using nginx, this location worked fine for me:

```
location ~ /app4/public/ {

error_log /apps/dss/websites/slim4_app_public.log;

try_files $uri $uri/ /app4/public/index.php;

include fastcgi.conf;

fastcgi_pass php-fpm-upstream;

}
```

php-fpm-upstream, in my system is:

```
upstream php-fpm-upstream {

server fpm80:9000;

}
```

Where fpm80 is the name of the container serving the php-fpm module.

Thank you Nigel and Michael.